# CE 1.9 - CSS class for CMS Page Layout update

Tags: layout, cms, layout-update, grid-layout

I've created a CMS page which has some content in it (intended to be a separate registration page for wholesale customers). The CMS Page content itself is a little write-up about registering as a wholesale customer, and I need for my register form to display to the right of it. I've also updated the layout XML as follows:

```
<reference name="content">
<block type="customer/form_register" name="customer_form_register" template="wholesale/customer/form/register.phtml">
    <action method="setShowAddressFields"><value>true</value></action>
    <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="customer.form.register.fields.before" as="form_fields_before" translate="label">
        <label>Form Fields Before</label>
    </block>
</block>
```

Layout is set as **1 Column**. My theme also utilises a CSS grid framework, and I would like for the page to display like so:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="columns grid12-5">
        <!--
            ***** CMS PAGE CONTENT GOES HERE *****
        -->
    </div>
    <div class="columns grid12-7">
        <!--
            ***** REGISTER FORM GOES HERE *****
        -->
    </div>
</div>
```

As it stands, they just stack vertically, with the register form showing beneath the CMS Page content. Is there anyway to achieve my desired output as above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, just realised that I'm calling the form in a block, so in the CMS Page Content Tab I ca just enter:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="columns grid12-5">
        <!--
            ***** CMS PAGE CONTENT GOES HERE *****
        -->
    </div>
    <div class="columns grid12-7">
        {{block type="customer/form_register" name="customer_form_register" template="wholesale/customer/form/register.phtml"}}
    </div>
</div>
```

I've customised the `register.phtml` template to show the fields I need it to.